# Unable to select range in reputation graph on stackoverflow profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-history

I'm unable to select a range on the graph of the reputation profile tab. It does work for me on meta stackexchange or programmers for example. Seems that only stackoverflow is affected.

I'm on Opera 29.0.1795.47 with Windows 7.